# groovy code for SVN/GIT checkout based on sourceURL

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, groovy

I want to write  groovy code which takes source URL input from Jenkins attributes and based on URL provided it has to do SVN checkout or GIT checkout

```
    >URL: HTTP://subversion/trunk
if (URL contains subversion)
{
//SVN checkout
}else (Source URL contains GIT){
//GIT checkout
}
```

I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to do your checkout, try the **Snippet Generator** in the section Pipeline syntax. Fill the informations and press **Generate Pipeline Script**. It should give you the correct checkout.

Comment: I have already used snippet generator to create SVN and Git checkouts separate. But I want to keep them both in if else loop and based on URL provided for checkout it has to run either SVN checkout or GIT checkout.

Comment: So your question is not about svn/git but about the sourceURL ?

Comment: I need groovy code to do as below:
soure URL: svn.com
if(sourceurl==svn){
//do svn checkout along with tag creation
}else {
//do git checkout along with tag creation
}